# Como enumerar bad smells em um software?

Tags: php, design-pattern, refatoração

Estou trabalhando em um sistema relativamente grande (considera-se inviável o esforço de reescrita) PHP que implementa de certa forma o padrão arquitetural MVC e que possui (sob um um ponto de vista mais elevado) diversos "bad smells". Acha se de tudo: de acoplamentos desnecessários, ausência de design patterns pra resolver problemas recorrentes e uso incorreto de herança e polimorfismo até mau uso de memória e impossibilidade de escalabilidade (através da criação de novas instâncias).

Foi me dado o desafio de limpar essa bagunça (penso eu que através de refatoração sobre refatoração), mas não sei exatamente por onde começar. Acredito que enumerar os problemas seria o primeiro passo a se tomar, e então **surgem as perguntas**: como posso listar os problemas do software para posterior análise? Existem ferramentas automatizadas que possam detectar problemas de forma discreta, ou agrupá-los?

Ressalto que não é viável a reescrita por conta do tempo investido, de regras de negócio obscuras e documentação inexistente.

Boa sorte pra mim.

Comment: Não acho que exista uma resposta "certa" no seu caso. IMHO o problema de não escalar deveria ser prioridade, porém não vejo como resolver esse tipo de problema apenas com refatoração.

Comment: @Pagotti certamente o problema da escalabilidade precisará de algo mais complexo, concordo. Quanto ao resto, você conhece alguma ferramenta automatizada que possa me dar um resumo sobre o uso de más práticas no código fonte? Não acho que seja prático enumerar tudo um a um.

Comment: Não conheço mas as indicadas pelo Gabriel parecem ajudar nesse sentido.

Comment: *1 banho ao dia deve resolver o problema de mau cheiro*. Agora falando sério, *bad smells* é também mais conhecido como *code smells*, o wikipedia até que está bem detalhado sobre o assunto https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell (inglês) para quem quiser saber do que se trata.

Comment: @Guilherme Conheço a terminologia "Code smell". Utilizei "bad smell" pra especificar que era um mau cheiro. Na minha graduação o professor utilizava a terminologia "good smell" para indicar um indício de um acerto ao implementar algo, logo acabei adquirindo o uso do termo.

Comment: Sim alguns usam uma maneira mais que outros, só coloquei para que as pessoas entendessem do que se refere.

Comment: Sugiro que quem marcou como "subjetiva" possa apontar a subjetividade após a edição.

Comment: Bem, eu votei a favor da sua questão, mas também votei para fechar. O problema a meu ver não é subjetividade, e sim a parte de ser dependente de opiniões. Acho que a parte meio difícil era o "**E a partir de então, por qual ordem seria mais eficiente começar a resolvê-los?**" que você já retirou da questão, isso era bem opinativo. Poderia argumentar mais uma ou outrra coisa na pergunta e também na resposta acerca do viés opinativo, mas repensando a situação, provavelmente isso seria pecar no excesso de rigidez. Vou votar para reabrir.

Comment: Removi essa parte referida embora ainda sinta que parte importante da questão precisou ser desprezada nesse processo. Se pensarmos de forma análoga a uma pergunta como "qual seria o algoritmo de busca mais eficiente na situação x" por exemplo, a eficiência seria mensurada dentre vários algoritmos para que se chegasse a uma resposta, e a mesma não seria "baseada em opinião" por existir um parâmetro quantitativo que seria independente da opinião do respondente. Esperava que se trouxesse uma abordagem comparativa na resposta e se chegasse a uma conclusão lógica, não subjetiva.

Comment: @CalebeOliveira esse é apenas o problema básico de consultar uma comunidade baseada em Q&A, existem perguntas que não podem ser respondidas segundo as regras e, ao meu ver, sãos as mais importantes.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Kent Beck trata mais como `bad smell` do que como `code smell` no livro "pai" do TDD. Qual é a confusão gerada? Sendo que o termo é majoritariamente utilizado pelo TDD.

Comment: @GabrielHeming está com certeza me levando a mal e confundindo tudo o que eu disse. Eu nunca li tal livro e só porque está em um livro não quer dizer que seja o mais usado. Só coloquei o link para para quem conhece como "Code smell" saber do que se trata "bad smell", não precisa fazer uma tempestade em copo um copo de água.

Comment: O mais bizarro de tudo é que o fechamento por "baseada em opinião" é puramente baseado em opinião, não havendo por exemplo um barema pra que se possa mensurar o quão baseada em opinião uma pergunta é; também há a suscetibilidade ao "comportamento de manada", onde votos quase aleatórios são induzidos e computados pela plataforma.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**TL ; DR**

> Como enumerar bad smells em um software?

- Mapeamento e relacionamento (em diagramas);
- TDD (o que não for encontrado por mapeamento, surge nos Testes, vide Liskov Substitution Principle);
- Compreensão do mapeamento com a necessidade do negócio (bad smells de negócio);
- Ferramentas auxiliares.

**Explicação**

Somente através de refatoração sobre refatoração não será o suficiente para "limpar" o sistema. Você até pode limpar uma unidade, mas ficará somente nisso.

Sua situação é bem delicada e de resolução lenta. Além disso, você pode encontrar/utilizar diversas abordagens. A que eu vou apresentar, seria mais uma mescla entre "conservadora" e "ágil", para evitar que a situação, na qual o sistema já se encontra, se repita.

Como você não irá reescrever o sistema inteiramente, deve ir em partes. A abordagem abaixo pode ser utilizada para ambos os cenários, apenas precisa encontrar e definir os limites da refatoração.

Primeiramente, mapear o componente que deseja refatorar:

- casos de uso;
- classes;
- storage;
- sequência;
- estados.

Com o mapeamento acima, você identificará como realmente é o ecossistema que deverá ser refatorado.

Após, faça a refatoração conceitual. Veja o estado que o sistema/componente se encontra, para onde e como, você deve levá-lo. Utilize os casos de uso do sistema para entender qual seria a integração/interação ideal entre os componentes.

Normalmente, nesses casos, o diagrama de casos de uso é a sua base de apoio para não perder o objetivo do sistema, junto com sequência e estados. Pois, se o sistema foi desenvolvido pensando no negócio, eles terão pouca, ou quase nenhuma, alteração. O que eu acredito que não é o seu caso.

Outro caso que deve ser ressaltado, é sobre o nível de refatoração. Se você refatorar apenas uma classe, sequência e estados são desnecessários. Entretanto, um conjunto de classes possui uma integração que não pode ser quebrada, e é por ai que encontrá a abordagem mais adequada.

Após o entendimento, vem a parte dramática. Escreva testes, muitos, intercalando em testes de unidade e de alto nível. Você precisará manter a integridade do sistema enquanto refatora o sistema. TDD será muito importante nessa etapa. Como diria Robert "UncleBob" Martin: "TDD é a documentação/manual do seu código"

Algumas ferramentas que podem lhe apoiar a nível de código:

- [PHP Mess Detector](https://phpmd.org/) (lhe informará sobre problemas de codificação, deixará seu código limpo e funcional);
- [PHP Code Sniffer](https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer) (manterá o seu sistema dentro dos padrões PSRs);
- [PHP Unit](https://phpunit.de/) (simplesmente TDD);
- [BlackFire.io](https://blackfire.io/) (realiza testes de performance do sistema, também mapeia todos as interações entre classes, poderá encontrar gargalos e interações ineficientes).
- [Astah Community](http://astah.net/editions/community) (todos os diagramas acima mencionados podem ser escritos nele)
- [MySQL WorkBench](http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/) (se o sistema for em MySQL, a engenharia reversa dessa ferramenta é realmente interessante).

Após o entendimento "superficial" de como realizar as modificações (modificações de baixo nível sempre surgem durante o processo de refatoração), utilize as 
Técnicas e princípios, abaixo, para guiar o desenvolvimento:

- TDD;
- [Refactoring](https://sourcemaking.com/refactoring);
- S.O.L.I.D ([Design Principles](http://butunclebob.com/ArticleS.UncleBob.PrinciplesOfOod) em geral);
- Object Calisthenics;
- Design Patterns.

Essas seriam as abordagens e ferramentas que eu utilizaria para refatorar um sistema já existente. Nada diferente do que eu faço no desenvolvimento de um sistema do zero.

Alguns links úteis:

- https://sourcemaking.com/;
- http://www.oodesign.com/;
- http://butunclebob.com/ArticleS.UncleBob.PrinciplesOfOod;
- https://codereview.stackexchange.com/;
- http://pt.slideshare.net/guilhermeblanco/php-para-adultos-clean-code-e-object-calisthenics;
- http://williamdurand.fr/2013/06/03/object-calisthenics/.

Adendo: não quero entrar em detalhes sobre se UML, Scrum ou qualquer outra metodologia é melhor. Apenas lhe informar sobre situações que podem ser previstas com um ou outro diagrama. Se não gostar de uma abordagem, utilize outra similar, pegue o que conhece de sua metodologia e aplique o que lhe trará confiança.

Comment: Como o sistema está muito acoplado com o banco de dados, com o servidor Apache e o sistema operacional, creio que também terei que criar uma VM ou containers do docker para replicar o ambiente todo.

Comment: Sim. Isole o seu ambiente. Tente trabalhar com correções progressivas e atualizações complementares, para que você possa atualizar uma parte do sistema (seja pequena ou grande) sem comprometer o funcionamento dele. Entender sobre integração contínua ajudaria (isso foge do meu conhecimento, meu foco é OO mesmo).

Answer (score 3):

## Dividir para Conquistar

Antes de tudo, é apenas uma opinião, um conjunto de dicas genéricas, talvez até o óbvio. Como regra geral, quando mais tarde você mexer no código, menos retrabalho terá.

Acho que nesse caso vale lembrar o Knuth:

> A otimização prematura é a raiz de todo mal. Programadores se
>   preocupam demais com a eficiência de código em lugares errados e na
>   hora errada.

Nas atividades é sempre bom criar diagramas, mesmo que sejam no papel. Desenhos te dão uma visão mais clara do que uma lista de problemas.

- **Componentes**. Procure desenhar o sistema de fora para dentro para saber quais são os módulos e componentes atuais e quais deveriam ser os módulos reais.
- **Dependências**. Identifique quais são as dependências entre as partes e as dependências que não deveriam existir. Existem dependências de outros componentes de terceiros, etc.
- **Comunicação**. Algo importante é como cada parte se comunica com a outra. O acoplamento de algumas partes pode ser desnecessário mas também pode não interferir na eficiência do todo. Com isso você pode escolher o que desacoplar e  o que não.
- **Gargalos**. Com as três primeiras você pode identificar as partes que vão impedir que você atenda aos novos requisitos (escalabilidade, por exemplo) e identificar o que você tem que resolver primeiro e o que pode ficar pro final.

A parte da refatoração em que você vai melhorar a manutenção futura do código ou vai facilitar o entendimento, vem depois que você tiver essa visão mais abrangente e puder dividir e priorizar o trabalho.

Boa sorte pra ti. =)